# Why is the use of "as effective as" wrong here?

Tags: phrases

From the SAT:

> Not many authors have described the effects of environmental pollution **as effective as** Rachael Carson, whose work is still a model for nature writers.

It said that **as effective as** is wrong here. Could someone explain why to me?

Comment: as......as   In your sentence there should be an adverb here, not an adjective.

Comment: Well, it's technically correct, but it implies that the author is a form of environmental pollution, which is a very strange thing to say.

Comment: Interesting, in my language (spanish), adjectives are allowed to be placed in the middle of *as.... as.*

Comment: Yes, adjectives can be used (as good as, as beautiful as) but not in your sentence.   Something is as...adjective...as.  You do something as ...adverb..as.

Comment: @Ale The issue is not word placement here. "Effective" should be "effectively."

Comment: I get that. I was poiting it to the adjective.

Comment: @Graffito, but the original sentence is easily understandable if we change "effective" to "effectively"; and since the OP states that "effective" is known to be wrong, trying to force a reading in which it is correct seems unproductive.

Comment: @Hellion - You are right: I deleted all my comments to limit pollution.

Answer (score 1):

**Effective**, an adjective, is describing **described**, a verb. This is grammatically incorrect because adjectives cannot be used to modify verbs. An adverb, *effectively*, should be used here instead.